# How to allocate memory fo array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, object, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to create an array of objects in C++. As C++ Supports native objects like int, float, and creating their array is not a problem.

But when I create a class and create an array of objects of that class, it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
```

```
class Employee
{
    string name;
    int age;
    int salary;

public:
    Employee(int agex, string namex, int salaryx)
    {
        name = namex;
        age = agex;
        salary = salaryx;
    }

    int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};
```

```
int main(void)
{
    Employee **mycompany = {};

    //Create a new Object
    mycompany[0] = new Employee(10, "Mayukh", 1000);
    string name = mycompany[0]->getName();
    cout << name << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

There is no compilation error, but when I'm running the Program, it is crashing. I don't know exactly what is happening here.

Please Help.

Here are some more details:

`OS: 64bit Windows 8.1 on Intel x64 (i3) Architecture of Compiler: MinGW64 G++ Compiler`

Comment: Your bug is here: `Employee **mycompany = {};` and `mycompany[0] = new Employee(10, "Mayukh", 1000);` if you are to create a 2D dynamic array you need to allocate the first dimension before using it.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Comment: @drescherjm, How should I do that? I tried doing `Employee *mycompany = {}` and removed the new keyword, as it is now pointing to objects, still my program crashes at runtime. Please Help.

Comment: I noticed when I use Vectors, it just works Fine. Please Tell Me Where I am wrong

Comment: `int main(void)
{
    
    vector<Employee> a;
    a.push_back(Employee(10, "Mayukh", 200));

    string name = a[0].getName();

    cout << name << "\n";

    return 0;
}`

Comment: A vector should be the preferred way unless an academic restriction prevents you from using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice here, as always, is to use some STL container, like an `std::vector`.

That said you're probably going to need a default `Employee` constructor (unless you always initialize *all* the elements of the container with the constructor you already have, which is unlikely what you'll do, if you are to manually allocate memory, but more likely if you use a `std::vector`).

```
//...
Employee() = default; // or Employee(){}
Employee(int agex, string namex, int salaryx)
{
    name = namex;
    age = agex;
    salary = salaryx;
}
//...
```

If you really, absolutely, must do it  by manual memory allocation, it would look roughly like this:

```
// Employee array with 5 employees, with the first two initialized with your constructor
Employee *mycompany = new Employee[5] {{10, "Mayukh1", 1000}, {20, "Mayukh2", 2000}};

//adding an employee
mycompany[2] = {30, "Mayukh3", 3000};

// it still has space for 2 more
```

Don't forget to delete the memory afterwards:

```
delete [] mycompany;
```

[**Live demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/cd9sT5aj4)

Answer (score 1):

this is how you would do that:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
    string name;
    int age;

    int salary;

    public:
        Employee(int agex, string namex, int salaryx)
        {
            name = namex;
            age = agex;
            salary = salaryx;
        }

        int getSalary()
        {
            return salary;
        }

        int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }

        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    //Create an Array length of 10 
    // in c++ its static you have to give the length of the array while declaring
    Employee mycompany [10];

    //Create a new Object
    mycompany[0] = new Employee(10, "Mayukh", 1000);

    string name = mycompany[0]->getName();

    cout << name << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that one, but my problem is I dont actually know the actual size of the array, meaning I'm Working with a dynamically sized array. Vector works just fine, But I want to know why my implementation does not works

Comment: You need default constructor, as mentioned in another answer. `Employee() = default; // or Employee(){}`

Comment: You can make a function that resizes the Array while you adding new objects to it
i did here with int but you can do it with Employee too 

```c++
void addToArray(int *&original, int &SIZE, const int &number)
{
 int *temporiginal = new int[SIZE + 1]; //(final)new array
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) //copy old array to new array
 {
  temporiginal[i] = original[i];
 }
        temporiginal[SIZE] = number
 delete[] original; //delete old array
 original = temporiginal; //point old array to new array
}

```

Comment: you can look here too :D
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/235218/
maybe ist clearer than

Comment: and yea you need a constructor too 
See here: https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_constructors.asp